# Kivy popup contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to use kivy as the graphical system and yet i dont know how to put inside a button and a label at the same time where label shows text and button closes popup also there is one import ant thing here it must be a function that can have editable title and contents and buttob(text) and can be launched like: self.popup(text1, text1, text3) Does anyone know how do it?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-popup-widget-in-kivy/

Comment: thanks you helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

**Kivy popup contents**: What do you want ? Nobody can answer this !!! Give a precise question (here are some propositions for your next SO post).

**I am trying to use kivy as the graphical system**: *How to use kivy app as a graphical system ?*

**and yet i dont know how to put inside a button and a label at the same time where label shows text and button closes popup**

- Kivy: how to add a widget (Label/Button) to an app ?
- Kivy: how to change Label text ?
- Kivy: how to bind a function on a button click ?
- Kivy: How to close a popup ?

**also there is one import ant thing here**: .

**it must be a function that can have editable title and contents and buttob(text)**:

- I think you should check out what theses terms are: POO, Inheritance, attribute, method.